# How to apply wild card and "not" in DB Browser for SQLite's "Browse Data" view?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have found this [reference](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Using-the-Filters), I like to filter out some rows that are of certain conditions but can't figure out how.

For example, a column contains

```
346    346.1    346.8    720.1
```

I want to filter out the ones assembled this form 346.x, such that 346.1 and 346.8 are gone.

I tried `<>346.1~9` and `<>346.%`, but both filter out everything.

Comment: `SELECT foo FROM your_table WHERE foo NOT LIKE '346.%'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no sugar coating it: According to the document you reference, you cannot. Under the [Supported Operators](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Using-the-Filters#supported-operators) section it says [emphasis added]:

> <>   | Unequal |     This is the opposite of the '=' operator, that is **no
>   wild cards allowed** and case-dependent search.